# What is the term for PIE yo > Gothic ji / Proto-Slavic jь?

Tags: slavic-languages, proto-germanic

What is the term for PIE *yos > Gothic ji?
PIE *kór**yo**s > Gothic har**ji**s
What is the term for PIE *yos > Proto-Slavi jь?
PIE *gʷo**y**h₃-**o**-s > Proto-Slavic *go**jь**

Comment: That’s not a thing. PIE _*i̯_ does not become Gothic _ji_ or Proto-Slavic _jь_. It’s the following thematic vowel that, in some cases, becomes a front vowel. The two changes are not related.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Could you please give the source?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet PGmc *bidisi > Gothic bidjis. Where is the thematic vowel?

Comment: That’s a completely unrelated thing (though the _i_ does happen to be a thematic vowel in origin). Gothic just analogically reinstated a _j_ that had disappeared in PG before front vowels.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Could you please cite.

Comment: You don’t even need a source for that. The PG verb had _*-j-_ everywhere in the present system except in _*bidisi_, _*bidiþi_ and _*bidiþ_ (as well as 2sg imperative _*bidi_); that’s 28 forms with _*-j-_ and three (four) without. Gothic has the _-j-_ in every single form in the present system (except for the 2sg imperative _bidei_ as if from _**bidiji_), and there is no sound change that would spawn a _-j-_ and turn _*-di-_ into _-dji-_. The added _-j-_ in these forms is found in all _j_-present verbs in Gothic. That is a very obvious case of analogy.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet First of all I want a source that  Gothic j**i** is from PIE thematic **o**. Secondly I want a source that Proto-Slavic j**ь** is not from PIE thematic **o**.

Comment: Gothic _harjis_ goes back to PG _*harjaz_, in which the second _*a_ is the regular outcome of PIE _*o_. The change from _*a_ to _i_ happened somewhere between PG and Gothic. I think the actual chain of events was _*harjaz_ > _*harjs_ ([loss of short unaccented vowels](https://jtauber.github.io/gothica/wright-1910-grammar/html/chapter05.html)) > _*haris_ (vocalisation of interconsonantal _*j_) > _harjis_ (analogical restitution of _j_ in _j_-stems). I believe the ь in PSl. _*gojь_ does come from the thematic vowel as the regular outcome of _*jə_ < PBSl. _*ja_ < PIE _*i̯o_, but I’m no Slavicist.

Comment: At any rate, it is not the case that PIE _*i̯_ becomes Gothic _ji_ or PSl. _*jь_. It may play a role in some circumstances that end up leading to those final output forms, but it is not a case of PIE _*i̯_ > Gothic _ji_, PSl. _*jь_.

Comment: The edit makes the question a lot better, and I’ve removed my downvote. I don’t think there’s a specific term for either development, but it’s possible it’s Someone’s Law (there are so many). But do remember that most historical sound changes do not have distinct names.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The regular outcome of  PBSl. ***a**s is **ъ**. The regular outcome of  PBSl. ***i**s is **ь**

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What about Gothic har**ji**s Lithuanian kar**y**s? Does Lithuanian "y" from the thematic vowel?

Comment: Yes, PBSl. _*-as_ generally gives PSl. _*-ъ_; but [Proto-Slavic vowel fronting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Proto-Slavic#Vowel_fronting) would, as far as I know, cause _*jъ_ to become _*jь_. [According to Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ys#Etymology_1), Lithuanian _-ys_ is indeed also from PBSl. _*-jás_; I presume a similar fronting rule applied there as well, but I’m no Balticist either.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What about Lithuanian [**ju**ngas](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jungas) (not yngas)

Comment: That’s from PIE _*i̯u_ (> PBSl. _*jū́ˀ_), not _*i̯o_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ["a similar fronting rule"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Proto-Slavic#Vowel_fronting) implies Jū → *Jī

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you for your link to [Proto-Slavic vowel fronting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Proto-Slavic#Vowel_fronting)